# Cypress testing Xero Authentication process

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, cypress, xero-api

I'm attempting to test the Xero Authentication process with Cypress, but I am encountering this error after I login with my correct login details.

Xero Auth Error -
[image]

Is there a way to fix this or is there an alternative someone can suggest?

Thank you and have a nice day!

Tried: Connecting to Xero through Cypress
Expecting: Successful Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

The error code indicates your ip address is being blocked by Xero's WAF. Have a look at this article for more information. Stopping actions listed in the article will allow the risk score to reset and restore access after around 24 hours.

https://community.akamai.com/customers/s/article/Why-is-Akamai-blocking-me?language=en_US

If you are not doing any of those things, please reach out to Xero via https://developer.xero.com/contact-xero-developer-platform-support/ with a very recent error code (the one starting #18.xxx) as the code is time-sensitive.